# Modelform with reverse foreignkey

Tags: django

I am trying to create a ModelForm for musician Model from which it must be possible to select 
a number of albums for each musician.Since album is reverse foreignkey i think 
ModelForm doesn't saves album values to the database.Is there any possible methods to get this working

please help me and thanks in advance

here is my modelform:

```
class musicianForm(forms.ModelForm):


   album=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Musician.objects.all(),
                                           widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple())


   class Meta:
       model = Musician
       fields = ('album','first_name','last_name','instrument')
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

## admin.py

```
class musicianAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = musicianForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to overwrite the `__init__` of your form like this:

```
class MusicianForm(forms.ModelForm):

    musician = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MusicianForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['musician'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(         
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
            choices=(((choice.id), choice) for choice in Musician.objects.all())
            )

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('name','release_date','num_stars')
```

Then in your `models.py` you will have to create another model to connect the artists to the albums. If you don't do this, you can only add one artist to an album (there might be collaborations, so we have to do this):

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AlMu(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then to process our data and connect everything, do this:

```
def create_album(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MusicianForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            mu = form.save(commit=False)
            mu.name =  form.cleaned_data['name']
            mu.release_date = form.cleaned_data['release_date']
            mu.num_stars = form.cleaned_data['num_stars']
            mu.save()
            for i in form.cleaned_data['musician']:
                mus = Musician.objects.get(id=i)
                AlMu(artist=mus, album=mu).save()
            # do something fancy here. Redirect or so
    else:
        form = MusicianForm()

    return render(request, 'create_album.html', {'form': form})
```

Your `create_album.html` file will look like this (nothing fancy):

```
<form method="POST">
    {{form}}
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: still no luck,album doesn't seem to be stored in the database.album returns an empty list.i think it is needed to override the save method

Comment: @KiranS am sorry for the late reply. I think I misunderstood the thing you want to do. In short: Do you want to get a list of checkboxes with all the musicians that are available and then check one (or two) and add those to an album? Is that correct?

Comment: @KiranS I have edited the code. I have tested this and it works. Is this what you are after?